# Embed the legend into the plot area of JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

In `JFreeChart`, is it possible to embed the legend into the chart itself?
Legend can be set on top, bottom, left, right of the chart as follows, but is it possible to imbed it into the chart?

```
LegendTitle legend=chart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an example of how to set the legend inside the polt are included in the [JFreeChart Samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) `XYTitleAnnotationDemo1`, this is the key part:

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
LegendTitle lt = new LegendTitle(plot);
lt.setItemFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 9));
lt.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(200, 200, 255, 100));
lt.setFrame(new BlockBorder(Color.white));
lt.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
XYTitleAnnotation ta = new XYTitleAnnotation(0.98, 0.02, lt,RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

ta.setMaxWidth(0.48);
plot.addAnnotation(ta);
```

[image]

Comment: How does that work with BoxAndWhisker plots? I don't know which annotation to use and how for the CategoryPlot.