# How to embed legend in jfreechart categoryplot?

Tags: embed, jfreechart, legend

I want to embed legend into categoryplot.

There is a example that is implemented with XYplot
([Embed the legend into the plot area of JFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320360/embed-the-legend-into-the-plot-area-of-jfreechart))

But, XYTitleAnnotation can be use only for XYplot.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A `CategoryPlot` doesn't have the notion of XY coordinates, but a [`CategoryTextAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/CategoryTextAnnotation.html) can be positioned as outlined [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4175).