# JFreeChart: Embed legend into boxplot

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, legend, boxplot

I'm using JFreeChart with Java to produce `BoxAndWhisker` boxplots. I want to embed the legend into the boxplot area.

I realize a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320360/embed-the-legend-into-the-plot-area-of-jfreechart) question has been asked for embedding the legend into the plot area in general. However, the answer does not work for boxplots because they do not work with `XYTitleAnnotation`s but with `CategoryAnnotation`s.

I don't know which `CategoryAnnotation` to use and how. None of the three implementing classes seem to have the functionality I want.

Is this even possible for boxplots? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible as the two implementations of `CategoryAnnotation` are used to annotate a Category and draw a line between two categories.

You can however move the position of the legend:

```
LegendTitle legend= localJFreeChart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
```

Comment: I was aware of that, but it doesn't actually help to save space and make the plots more compact. I'll probably get rid of the whole legend then.