# Reduce space between legend and chart in jfree Pie chart

Tags: jfreechart, pie-chart

I placed the legend in the top left corner and there is an unnecessary gap between the chart and the legend.
How to reduce this?

There is considerable amount of space between pie chart and its border.

```
public void setPie() {
    RingPlot plot = (RingPlot) this.chart.getPlot();

    plot.setSectionPaint("", WHITE_COLOR);
    plot.setCircular(true);
    plot.setShadowPaint(null);
}

public void setLegend() {
    LegendTitle legend = this.chart.getLegend();
    legend.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
    legend.setVisible(true);
    legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.LEFT);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(LEGEND_LENGTH, LEGEND_WIDTH);
    RingPlot plot = (RingPlot) this.chart.getPlot();
    plot.setLegendItemShape((Shape) rect);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try tweaking the margins around the `LegendTitle`. Something like:

```
chart.getLegend().setMargin(top, left, bottom, right);
```

EDIT: As suggested in the post in the comments, you could try to draw the legend manually at a given position:

```
//Print legend at X & Y location 
Rectangle2D r2DD = new Rectangle2D.Double(119, 47, 120, 180);
LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(chart.getPlot());
legendTitle.draw(g2,r2DD);
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it, as you need access to the `ChartPanel`'s `Graphics2D`. Perhaps by extending `ChartPanel` and overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` ?

Comment: Thanks. This gives some space. But there is considerable amount of space mainly between pie chart and its border. Any idea how to reduce that?

Comment: This is probably because the legend is outside the plot area. Perhaps you could try positioning the legend inside the plot area? See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320360/embed-the-legend-into-the-plot-area-of-jfreechart

Comment: This is anotated for XYPlot. Is there a way to anotate it for RingPlot?

Comment: According to this http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html there is no annotation for RingPlot. Is there any workaround to get the legend inside the plot area?

Comment: You can manually create and draw the legend at a specific location, as proposed in this post: http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14632

Comment: I tried what above post suggests. But no luck. Can you please clarify that? I have added the code of my chart.